# variable = worksheet (=>expected identifier)

Tags: excel, vba, identifier, worksheet

First of all, sorry for my bad English

So I have a macro that sets the worksheets of my workbook as variables names to prevent having to debug alert when a user uses the workbook and changes the name or the position of a sheet.

For example, if my sheet's name is "BDD" when I code I will be referring to this sheet as Sheets("'BDD").xxxxxx or sheets(1).xxxxxxx then if a user changes the name of the sheet my macros will not work anymore

That's why in worbook_open I set:

```
WB00 = activeworkbook
WB00WS01 = first sheet
WB00WS02 = second sheet
```

on and on

Therefore, when I code I refer to it as WB00WS01.xxxx

So, my macro is:

```
    Sub initWB00()
        Set WB00 = ActiveWorkbook
        For Each W In WB00.Worksheets
            On Error Resume Next
            If W.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then
                Set WB00WS01 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil2" Then
                Set WB00WS02 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil3" Then
                Set WB00WS03 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil4" Then
                Set WB00WS04 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil5" Then
                Set WB00WS05 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil6" Then
                Set WB00WS06 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil7" Then
                Set WB00WS07 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil8" Then
                Set WB00WS08 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil9" Then
                Set WB00WS09 = W
            End If
            If W.CodeName = "Feuil10" Then
                Set WB00WS10 = W
            End If
        Next W
    End Sub
```

It works as it is, but as you can see, it's pretty limited (if I want to go up to WB00WS100 for example) and it's very trivial

Then, I had the idea to loop a variable "i" that will give the number of the sheet `"WB00WS" & i = "sheet" & I`

```
Sub initWB00()
Dim i As Integer
    Set WB00 = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each W In WB00.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 20
        If W.CodeName = "Feuil" & i Then
            Set "WB00WS0"&i = W
        End If
        Next i
    Next W
End Sub
```

If I do it like that I have the expected identifier error

I assume it's because I've put a string and a variable to the left of equality but otherwise I can't imagine how can I write a loop that makes what I need to

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Congrats on a pretty well written first question! Your English seems quite fine btw. Sadly, you cannot make a variable name from a string, so what you're trying to do cannot work. Maybe use arrays instead. But honestly, that doesn't seem like a great solution... IMO, either trust your users to not rename sheets or protect them.

Comment: Ok Victor, thank you for the very pleasant welcoming and for the answer, have a good day !

Comment: If you look at the Project pane in VBE, each `Sheet` has 2 names - The internal name and display name in bracket (which is shown and can be edited by user). You can refer to the internal name in your code and it doesn't matter whether the user renames the sheet or not.

Comment: Does the array solution just not replace the `Worksheets` collection?  Is the best approach a function that extracts the numeric from `WB00WS099` and translates to `worksheets("Feuil99")` returning a worksheet?

Comment: @RaymondWu actually I tried this method (changes the codename) :
```
Sub initWB00()
Dim i As Integer
    Set WB00 = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each W In WB00.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 2
        If W.CodeName = "Feuil" & i Then
        W.Parent.VBProject.VBComponents(W.CodeName).Properties("_CodeName") = "WB00WS" & i
        End If
        Next i
    Next W
End Sub
```
That worked for almost all of my macros but ones like WB00WS01 couldnt launch, do you know why

Comment: Shouldn't it be better to change the `CodeName`, running the code once and then only use the newly created ones? I posted a piece of code doing that...

Comment: @babozo I'm not even sure why you are trying to do this, in your example - If your `Sheets("'BDD")` 's `CodeName` is "shtBDD" Then in your code you refer to it as `shtBDD.XXXX` instead of `Sheets("BDD").XXXX`.

Comment: @RaymondWu this doesnt work for all my macros, i now have a missing object error

Comment: @babozo Are you referring to worksheet(s) that does not belong to `ThisWorkbook` where the code runs?

Comment: i'm referring only to thisworkbook, in fact, i only use one workbook

Comment: @babozo I suggest you update your question with a screenshot of the `Missing Object` error and your Project pane with the worksheet in question.

Comment: I've added the link to the file, do you want me to send you a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try using of the next approach. You will run the code once and all the sheets code names will be changed. Then, you must only use them:

```
Sub initWB00()
    Dim i As Long, w As Worksheet, WB00 As Workbook
    
    Set WB00 = ActiveWorkbook 'if the active workbook is not ThisWorkbook, it will change the names of he active workbook sheets.
                              'but they can be used only running codes inside them
                              'In order to not have such problems, you should use ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbook 
    For Each w In WB00.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 20
            If w.CodeName = "Feuil" & i Then
                ChangeCodeName w, WB00, "WB00WS0" & i
            End If
        Next i
    Next w
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeCodeName(sh As Worksheet, WB As Workbook, strCodeName As String)
  Dim shCModule As Object
  Set shCModule = WB.VBProject.VBComponents(sh.CodeName)
  shCModule.Name = strCodeName
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to change the codename of my sheets. That worked for almost all of my macros but ones like WB00WS01 couldnt launch, do you know why ?

Comment: @babozo No reason for any sheet to not be recognized according to such a name. I tested now this name and it works. But you must know that this way of calling works **only for the ThisWorkbook**. How did you try using it?

Comment: Like that:
Sub Opener()
WB00WS01.Unprotect Password:="UNLOCK"
Locked = False
End Sub
I have a missing object error

Comment: @babozo Does `WB00WS01` belong to the workbook where the above code runs?

Comment: absolutely, I used the macros that you gave me

Comment: @babozo That macro is tricky... Probably, I should state the importance of the used workbook. If you used it **as it is** and **another workbook was activated, not ThisWorkbook**, it changed the code name to that workbook. And it makes sense only for `ThisWorkbook`. The one keeping the code which try using the code name... The idea was that you can change the code name in any workbook, **but it must be a type accepting macros in order to be used**. Only inside of the workbook running the macro...

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm not clear enough and if you are struggling with me..
I'm lauching your macro in the workbook adequate, i see the codenames of all the sheets changing but i still have this object error

Comment: @babozo Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem... Of course, not using `Locked = False` and it worked. It works and it should work. What is `Locked` in the code you try? Shouldn't it be the real problem?

Comment: Locked is just a boolean needed elsewhere, i have added the link to the file, could you please look at it when you got the time and tell me if there is anything that im not doing like you did ?

Comment: @babozo If not anything confidential in your workbook, can you share it? I would like testing it, if possible. Another issue: Do you see the sheet in discussion having that code name?

Comment: Added! 
And yes i see it changing

Comment: @babozo I am looking at your file and the code name, as the code sets does not work, indeed. But I did the same on a fresh workbook, naming the sheets in exactly the same way and it works like it should. I do not understand what problem exists in your workbook. Please, try it on another workbook and see what's happening. Of course, a xlsm type...

Comment: @babozo Ups... I could not analyze all your code. It just didn't work, I did not clearly understand what is your problem with `ThisWorkbook`. If you declared the variable **in a standard module** as `Public`, you can initialize it anywhere and used (after that) wherever you need...

Answer (score 1):

This is one method for populating an array with references to worksheets and emulates the attempts you have made in your code.  However, the point made by Raymond Wu is possibly the more correct solution.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function initWB00(ByRef ipWB As Workbook) As Variant
    
    Dim myWorksheetArray As Variant
    ReDim myworksheet(1 To ipWB.Worksheets.Count)
    
    Dim myItem As Variant
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    For Each myItem In ipWB.Worksheets
    
        ' The next line just allow intellisense
        Set mySheet = myItem
        If InStr(mySheet.CodeName, "Sheet1") Then
        
            Set myWorksheetArray(1) = mySheet
            
        Else
        
            Set myWorksheetArray(CLng(Split(mySheet.CodeName, "l")(1))) = mySheet
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
    initWB00 = myWorksheetArray
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it and i'll get to you !

Comment: Nice idea. It is a small typo (`ReDim myworksheet` instead of `ReDim myWorksheetArray`) in the code. And, if there are gaps between the sheets number because of sheet(s) delition, it will be difficult to refer the correct sheet using the array. But, anyhow, I like the code idea... Voted up.

Comment: @FaneDuru  Whoops, sorry about the typo.  Testing for IsEmpty before accessing a sheet via the array would be the sensible and safe way to go.

Comment: I am afraid nothing will be empty... If there are gaps, `Worksheets.Count` returns 10 and there are sheets named as "Sheet12" construction `Set myWorksheetArray(CLng(Split(mySheet.CodeName, "l")(1))) = mySheet` will fail because of exceeding of the array `Ubound`. It should be better to use a variable and increment it after each loading of each array element.  And it looks to be another type: `, "l")(1))` works for names like "Feuil" and the code still keeps "Sheet1", probably since you tested it.

Comment: @FaneDuru  My answer was a technology demonstrator to help the OP understand how to use and array to capture worksheet references.  It did compile without error but I didn't run it because I don't have the host workbook.  I'm happy to provide further assitance if the OP needs it.

Comment: That's why I voted it up. Then, I only expressed some opinions about the way of an eventual optimization, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Soooooooooooooooo Thanks to @FaneDuru I've found a solution ! I just had to remove the Global appelation at the start of my code (I had Global WB00WS01, Global WB00WS2...) and it worked !

My only problem left is that somewhere in my code I Set WB00 as ThisWorkbook and i cant refer to it later in my code. Even when I Dim WB00 as Workbook in the header of my code. When I use `WB00.Windows(1).VisibleRange(2, 2).Top` i have an undefined variable error

Anyway, thanks to all of you for helping me out !!

Comment: You should just use `ThisWorkbook` since it's exactly the same thing. the state of a variable can be lost when you reset or end in the event of an error whereas `ThisWorkbook` is always there.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the purpose of your file but I suggest you remove it since there's no need to share it for debugging purpose. It could have sensitive data?